# How to read property from service.php config in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I tried to read as:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

echo Config::set("services.sparkpost.secret");
```

It reproduces an error

Comment: Can you post the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`set()` method sets variable, not getting it. You can use `get()` method instead of you can just use `config()` helper to get the config data from any class of an app:

```
config('services.sparkpost.secret')
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch it from `set` to `get`

```
echo Config::get("services.sparkpost.secret");
```

You can also use the global helper method:

```
echo config("services.sparkpost.secret");
```

You can read more about `config` in the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#accessing-configuration-values).

> You may easily access your configuration values using the global
>   config helper function from anywhere in your application. The
>   configuration values may be accessed using "dot" syntax, which
>   includes the name of the file and option you wish to access.

Comment: It does not work, I forgot to change in question set to get :)